# Flow object value based on key

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When using flow, I've been wanting to type something like this:

```
type Item = {
  timestamp: number,
  status: { completed: boolean },
  data: string,
}

type Filter = {
  timestamp: number,
  status: { completed: boolean },
}

const FilterFns: {
  [key: $Keys<Filter>]: ($ElementType<Filter, key>, item: Item) => boolean
} = {
  timestamp: (timestamp, item) => timestamp === item.timestamp,
  status: (status, item) => status.completed === item.status.completed,
}
```

But I get the error:

```
13:   [key: $Keys<Filter>]: ($ElementType<Filter, key>, item: Item) => boolean
                                                  ^ Cannot resolve name `key`.
```

If instead I define `FilterFns` as:

```
const FilterFns: {
  [key: $Keys<Filter>]: ($Values<Filter>, item: Item) => boolean
} = {
  timestamp: (timestamp, item) => timestamp === item.timestamp,
  status: (status, item) => status.completed === item.status.completed,
}
```

I get the error:

```
16:   status: (status, item) => status.completed === item.status.completed,
                                       ^ Cannot get `status.completed` because property `completed` is missing in `Number` [1].
References:
8:   timestamp: number,
                ^ [1]
```

What's the correct way to ensure that the first argument passed into the function in the value of `FilterFns` is the corresponding type in `Filter`?

Comment: Flow playground with code above -> https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8BQUrAJYIgGdgBDBMALigDsBXBAIwgCcAaLKYk4WwqtKAGMA9uQA2EeABMqDYcIklqUAL7tsU7iSrFmuagHN2KjBlCQoAMVxj4zFOg54CXclTqMW6zqR590QqJgEtKy8orKahgmGCLUxFY2dpbx-BwA2gDWECBUACQA0jmEADzWtiwAfAC6VAAUeQBqJGK0RGVJVaxQuPAIVHCIAJQolVByChBK0Q6Y2M5EpG5QdQuuYN29w6M4+ItkYCjIqFsIAHRrSxscXH71t7ybfSPIY+YQwgBmPty8R6gAcmEDAAVhBBMAAVAAGTQn5+M4icSSCBSf49PpnB6ERFBEKo4xAA

Answer (score 1):

Not the general solution for the problem with object keys, but a particular case can be solved in next one way

```
type Item = {
  timestamp: number,
  status: { completed: boolean },
  data: string,
}

type Filter = {
  timestamp: number,
  status: { completed: boolean },
}

const FilterFns: {
  [key: $Keys<Filter>]: ($Values<Filter>, item: Item) => boolean
} = {
  timestamp: (timestamp, item) => timestamp === item.timestamp,
  status: (status, item) => typeof status === 'object' && status.completed === item.status.completed,
}
```

adding additional condition `typeof status === 'object'` will allow flow to identify on what exactly value it is right now, otherwise flow do not get pairs keys - values right, unfortunately